# Warning FS1178 "does not support structural equality"

Tags: f#

I tried enabling warnings level 5 over a large codebase and it mostly triggered hundreds of these:

> Warning   FS1178  The struct, record or union type 'Foo' does not support
> structural equality because the type '(unit -> IBar option)' does not
> satisfy the 'equality' constraint. Consider adding the 'NoEquality'
> attribute to the type 'Foo' to clarify that the type does not support
> structural equality

Many of our types reference C# types, or contain function types (like the above). What would it gain us to go through all of these and the `NoComparison`/`NoEquality` attributes as required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try to compare `Foo` instances elsewhere in your code, the presence of `[<NoComparison>]` or `[<NoEquality>]` on `Foo` will make the compiler errors generated by that subsequent code easier to understand.

Example without attribute:

```
type Foo =
    {
        Func : int -> int
    }

let problem = Set<Foo>

(*
Compiler error:
The type 'Foo' does not support the 'comparison' constraint
because it is a record, union or struct with one or more
structural element types which do not support the
'comparison' constraint. Either avoid the use of comparison
with this type, or add the 'StructuralComparison' attribute
to the type to determine which field type does not support
comparison
*)
```

Example with attribute:

```
[<NoComparison>]
type Foo =
    {
        Func : int -> int
    }

let problem = Set<Foo>

(*
Simpler compiler error:
The type 'Foo' does not support the 'comparison' constraint
because it has the 'NoComparison' attribute
*)
```

Comment: I think I actually prefer the first error as it doesn't rely on user-provided, possibly inaccurate information. If I later change the type so that it becomes structurally comparable, I have to remember to remove the NoComparison attribute and transitively do that for all types using it.

Comment: That's reasonable. You can just suppress the FS1178 warning if you want.